# print from android to wifi printer

Tags: android, printing, wifi

I have a Samsung ML-2165W printer wifi and I want to print from my app, I have tried with the socket code and library iPrint.jarn, and nothing, the connection is successful!, but printing is not successful, could help me? may be a compatibility issue with iPrint.jar printer? Help please!

Comment: You need to post some of your code to help others understand what to help you with.

Comment: What's the code, what's the error. Needs more info.

Answer (score 0):

you can do with the send2printer installed and the third party sdk .

you must see this:
http://hit-mob.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=66